# Javascript, Chrome don't recognise the variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, html

I hope you are well!!

Recently I created this calculator following a tutorial on youtube.
How you can see below I put all the variable outside the function.
In Firefox is working fine, but if I use Google Chrome and I try to use it, is giving me the result of NaN..... I fixed this error moving the var inside the function, but I don't understand why with Chrome I have to move it inside and Firefox no....

If anyone would be able to give me an explanation I will really appreciate!

Thanks!!!!

```js
var value1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#textbox1").value);
var value2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#textbox2").value);
var operator = document.querySelector("#operators").value;
var total = document.getElementById("total");
var calculate;

function result() {
  if (operator === "add") {
    calculate = value1 + value2;
  } else if (operator === "sub") {
    calculate = value1 - value2;
  } else if (operator === "multiply") {
    calculate = value1 * value2;
  } else if (operator === "divide") {
    calculate = value1 / value2;
  }
  total.innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="textbox1">
  <input type="text" id="textbox2"><br>
  <select id="operators">
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <option value="sub">Sub</option>
    <option value="multiply">Multiply</option>
    <option value="divide">Divide</option>

  </select>
  <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Result" onclick="result()">
  <div id="total"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're grabbing the values **before** the user fills them in, right away, when the page loads. (You've said it's "working" in Firefox. It doesn't for me, but if you have autofill enabled, it may be filling in values from a previous run.)

Instead, grab the values *within* the `result` function:

```js
var total = document.getElementById("total");

function result() {
  var value1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#textbox1").value);
  var value2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#textbox2").value);
  var operator = document.querySelector("#operators").value;
  var calculate;

  if (operator === "add") {
    calculate = value1 + value2;
  } else if (operator === "sub") {
    calculate = value1 - value2;
  } else if (operator === "multiply") {
    calculate = value1 * value2;
  } else if (operator === "divide") {
    calculate = value1 / value2;
  }
  total.innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="textbox1">
  <input type="text" id="textbox2"><br>
  <select id="operators">
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <option value="sub">Sub</option>
    <option value="multiply">Multiply</option>
    <option value="divide">Divide</option>

  </select>
  <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Result" onclick="result()">
  <div id="total"></div>
</form>
```